# this.$emit does not work in 'mounted' method of vue.js component

Tags: vue.js

`this.$emit` does not work in `mounted` hook. How to deal with it?
I have to add `setTimeout` but it is bad idea.

```
mounted() {
  this.input = $(this.$el).find('.after-input');
  if(this.propEmitChangedOnMount && !this.isDisabled) {
    this.$nextTick(() => {
      console.log(this.propName); console.log(this.value);
      setTimeout(() => {
        this.$emit('changed', this.propName, this.value);
      }, 1900); // i have to add timeout to trigger change on mount
    });
  }
},
```

Inside `watcher` it works fine.

```
watch: {
     propInitialValue: function(val, oldVal) {
         this.value = this.getValue(val);
     },
     value: function(val, oldVal) {
         if( ! this.isDisabled ) {
             this.$emit('changed', this.propName, val);
         }
     }
 },
```

Comment: events can only emit one value. If you are using vue-devtools: https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/vuejs-devtools/nhdogjmejiglipccpnnnanhbledajbpd you can see if the event was fired.

Comment: Nope, many values. this.$emit works in other methods. Or with setTimeout in this case.

Comment: Try using `this.$emit('changed', {prop: this.propName, value: this.value});` I can't find it anywhere, but I am confident that events cant emit multiple values like that.

Comment: They can http://i.imgur.com/Tr9G9ix.png

Comment: Oh, so it made an array out of it. So if you add a `setTimeout()` it fires the event but not otherwise?

Comment: Yes, only with `setTimeout` (inside `mounted` hook).
But inside `watch` it works without any timeouts. I guess, that inside `mounted` events are not ready yet. May be there is another hook which I can use to trigger event upon creating component?

Comment: it depends when you want to trigger this event - did you tried with `created` hook ?

Comment: There shouldn't be any issue emitting from the mounted hook: https://jsfiddle.net/6w4ax8r1/  Something else must be going on.

Answer (score 0):

Add `.bind(this)`

```
setTimeout(() => {
  this.$emit('changed', this.propName, this.value);
}, 1900).bind(this)
```